# Can a Light domain cleric's Warding Flare be used in response to an Attack of Opportunity?

Tags: dnd-5e, cleric, opportunity-attack, reactions

Say a Light domain cleric is adjacent to a hostile creature, and attacks the enemy as its action.  After the action, the cleric moves away from the creature, provoking an attack of opportunity, which the hostile creature does.  Since the attack of opportunity is a reaction, and the cleric's Warding Flare is also a reaction, do the RAW allow for the cleric to emit its warding flare as it flees the enemy and its opportunity attack?

**Light Domain cleric warding flare PHB pg 61:**

> **Warding Flare**
>   Also at 1st level, you can interpose divine light between yourself and an attacking enemy. When you are attacked by a creature within 30 feet of you that you can see,
>   you can use your reaction to impose disadvantage on
>   the attack roll, causing light to flare before the attacker before it hits or misses. An attacker that can’t be blinded is immune to this feature.
>   You can use this feature a number of times equal to your Wisdom modifier (a minimum of once). You regain all expended uses when you finish a long rest.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes.

> Certain special abilities, spells, and situations allow
>   you to take a special action called a reaction. A reaction
>   is an instant response to a trigger of some kind, which
>   can occur on your turn or on someone else’s. The
>   opportunity attack, described later in this chapter, is the
>   most common type of reaction.
>   -PHB Page 190